# Как заставить div не преходить вниз?

Tags: html, css

Есть такой HTML code:

```
<div id=header>

<div id=logo>

</div>
<div id=logospliter>

</div>
<div id=PrStudio >

</div>       
<div id=ActivePart >
</div>

</div>
```

Css:

```
#header
{
    height: 230px;
    width: 900px;    
    border: 1px;
    border-color: #FF0000;
    border-style: solid;    
    white-space: nowrap;    
    display:inline-block
    }

#header #logo
{
    height: 230px;
    width: 348px;
    background-image: url(../images/Logo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    background-position: center center;
    display:inline-block

    }
#header #logospliter
{
    height: 230px;
    width: 50px;
    background-image: url(../images/LogoSpliter.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    background-position: center center;
    display:inline-block
    }
#header #ActivePart
{
    border: 1px;
    border-color: #FF0000;
    border-style: solid;        
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    display:inline-block
    }

#header #PrStudio {
    background-image: url(../images/aa.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
    height: 230px;
    width: 398px;
    float: left;
    display:inline-block
}
```

Размер `div-a ActivePart` может меняться. Как заставить его не преходить вниз, если он выходит за пределы `div-a header`?

Comment: У меня везде было В CSS
и float: left;
и display:inline-block
убрал float: left; при пустых дивах все так как надо но стоит только ввести текст в какойто див они вобне непонятно как дергаться начинают.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У элемента `#header` вместо `width: 900px;` поставьте `min-width: 900px;`

Вообще, у вас очень странная верстка. Можно же [намного проще](http://cssdesk.com/Lbnw5) сделать:

```
#header {
  height: 230px;
  width: 900px;    
  padding: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#header > div {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}

#logo {
  outline-color: green;
  height: 230px;
  width: 348px;
}

#logospliter {
  outline-color: gray;
  height: 230px;
  width: 50px;
}

#ActivePart {
  outline-color: red;
  height: 200px;
}

#PrStudio {
  outline-color: blue;
  height: 230px;
  width: 398px;
}​
```

Comment: не помогает

Да и min-width меня не устроит т.к. header не должен увеличиваться

Хотя с  vertical-align: top; помогло сравнительно вот если еше както заставить на увеличиваться див будет то что надо

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Заметил помогло Спасибо

А верстка странная т.к. CSS из ПХП генерируется но над оптимизацмей подумаю